# cal.dateBySettingHour causing memory leak (Xcode 7.0.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I have narrowed a massive memory leak down to the second of the lines below:

```
let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let newDate: NSDate = cal.dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: inputDate, options: NSCalendarOptions())!
```

inputDate is a standard NSDate()
The routine is part of a phalanx of calculations each of which get called 500k times to do a year's calculations. With this line in it crashes after 300k cycles having used 440Mb of memory.

Comment: Are you instantiating the NSCalendar each time?  You can create it once and hold it in a property.

Comment: Yes, if I run the first line in the loop I don't have this problem. It's the second line that is causing the memory haemorage and also executes noteable slower. I am probably running 200 lines of trigonometry on each loop and it is 15 times slower when the second line is included.

I will still try your recommendation and report back - many thanks.